# Required field in a form

Tags: php, html

i have a simple form and i need that some fields are required.

I do not understand why they do not work. In fact, if I click on the Send button, it takes me to an error page.
I have tried inserting both the required = "required" and only required.
How can I do according to you?
Thank you for your time and availability.

```
<h3>&ensp;Dati Prenotazione</h3>
&ensp;Inserire i dati richiesti:<br><br>
<form method="post" action="input.php">
    <b>&ensp;Richiedente Conferenza:</b><br><br>
    &ensp;Nominativo:<br>&ensp;<input type="text" name="nominativo" placeholder="Nome Cognome" size="20" required="required"><br>
    &ensp;Email: <br> &ensp;<input type="email" name="email" size="20" placeholder="email" required><br>
    &ensp;Oggetto Conferenza:<br>&ensp;<textarea name="oggetto" rows="5" cols="40" placeholder="Specificare oggetto Videoconferenza" required></textarea><br>
    &ensp;Data: <br>&ensp;<input  type="date" name="data" required ><br>
    &ensp;Orario Inizio: <br>&ensp;<input type="time" name="orario_inizio" min="09:30:00" max="16:30:00" required ><br>
    &ensp;Orario Fine: <br>&ensp;<input type="time" name="orario_fine" min="10:00:00" max="18:30:00" required><br>

    <br>
    <b>&ensp;Partecipanti Interni </b>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="interni">
        <div id="first">
            &ensp;Nominativo:<br>&ensp;<textarea name="nominativoi" rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="Nome Cognome;" required ></textarea><br>
            &ensp;Email:<br>&ensp; <textarea  name="emaili" rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="Inserire Email" required></textarea><br>
```

input.php

```
require ('config.php');

// Richiedente
$nominativo = $_POST['nominativo'];

$email = $_POST['email'];
$oggetto = $_POST['oggetto'];
$data = $_POST['data'];
$orario_inizio = $_POST['orario_inizio'];
$orario_fine = $_POST['orario_fine'];
$stanza = 0;

// Personale Interno
$nominativoi = $_POST['nominativoi'];
$emaili = $_POST['emaili'];

// Persona Esterno
$nominativoe = $_POST['nominativoe'];
$emaile = $_POST['emaile'];

//aggiunta di un'ora ( per tornare indietro cambiare $newTimeEnd con $orario_fine
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $orario_fine);
$dateInterval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 hour');

$dateTime->add($dateInterval);    
$query1 = "INSERT INTO prenotazione (nominativo,email,data,orario_inizio,orario_fine,oggetto,nominativoi,emaili,nominativoe,emaile,stanza) VALUES ('$nominativo','$email','$data','$orario_inizio','$newTimeEnd','$oggetto','$nominativoi','$emaili','$nominativoe','$emaile',1)";

        $result1 = $dbh->prepare($query1);
        $result1->execute();
        $rex = 1;        

    }
    else if ($prenotato == 1 AND $prenotatoaccettato == 0 ){

        $query1 = "INSERT INTO prenotazione (nominativo,email,data,orario_inizio,orario_fine,oggetto,nominativoi,emaili,nominativoe,emaile,stanza) VALUES ('$nominativo','$email','$data','$orario_inizio','$newTimeEnd','$oggetto','$nominativoi','$emaili','$nominativoe','$emaile',2)";
        $result1 = $dbh->prepare($query1);
        $result1->execute();
        $rex = 1;
    }
```

> EDIT.

When i click submit the error is 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function add() on boolean 
( about `$dateTime->add($dateInterval);`  )

Comment: I have tested your code and all the required flags working. Did you use Javascript for Submit your Form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check required fields in your code

```
if (empty($_POST["nominativo"])) {
    addError('nominativo','nominativo error text');
  } else {
    $nominativo = $_POST["nominativo"];
 }


Nome Cognome : <input type="text" name="nominativo">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $nominativoErr;?></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't you problem rather in the input.php (can you post it ?) ? Are you sure of the path ?

Also, don't trust what is sent, make a validation in your php too, the HTML and JS code can be changed by the user.

Comment: I post my input.php

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like:

```
if($email==NULL|$data==NULL) {
?>
<script>
alert("Missing Fields!");
location.href="form1.html";// page where ir your form 
</script>

<?php
}
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+$/", $email)) {
exit('The email format is incorrect.');
}
```